# Set Template reference variables from property

Tags: angular, templates

Is it possible to set a `Template reference variable` from the property of a component in the template html?

For example:

```
export class TestComponent {
  private uniqueID : string; // set randomly
}
```

and in the HTML use it like this?

```
<input #uniqueID="ngModel">
<div [hidden]="['uniqueID'].valid || ['uniqueID'].pristine"></div>
```

I want to be able to set the template reference variable from my component because the input is being made multiple times in a `ngFor`(so keeping track of the state might cause an issue). Any suggestions?